# Help on a use of 「ところ」?

Tags: grammar, translation

Watching a show, I came across the sentence

> ２年前とは別人だってところをお見せします

What confuses me is the use of 「ところ」. I have seen 「ところ」 be used after verbs to give them a temporal-context, but this seems different because it is used after a noun.

I would translate the sentence as, "I will show that I am a different person from two years ago".

Is the 「ところ」giving a time related context to the sentence (i.e. the person changing)? And is 「ところ」used often after nouns like this?

Answer (score 2):

ところ has a lot of abstract meanings, and this ところ refers to "scene" or "situation".

- 彼が怒っているところを見た。
  I saw him get mad.
- お休みのところ申し訳ありません。
  I'm sorry to bother you on your day off.

Your translation attempt is correct, but note that 2年前とは別人だってところ refers to some *visible scene* that will take place and proves he has changed. Maybe you could translate it as "I'll show you the evidence ～" or "I'll show you how I have changed ～".